# /dev/dvd is missing on my centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, mount

I just installed a minimal centos 6 through a usb dvd writer. It worked fine. But now I can't mount the dvd writer. I can't even found the /dev/dvd device. I guess a drivers is missing, but how do I find the driver?

Some output from the system.

```
[root@]# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0000:0000  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0409:0056 NEC Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The NEC device is my DVD writer.

```
[root@]# lsusb -v # Only output for Nec driver.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0409:0056 NEC Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0409 NEC Corp.
  idProduct          0x0056 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 TSST corp
  iProduct                2 USB Mass Storage Device
  iSerial                 3 000000000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      5 SFF-8070i
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Everything related to usb in the /dev folder.

```
[root]# cd /dev
[root]# find | grep usb
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-mouse
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-mouse/c13:33
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-id\x2fusb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-mouse
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-id\x2fusb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-mouse/c13:33
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-event-mouse
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-event-mouse/c13:68
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-id\x2fusb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-event-mouse
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-id\x2fusb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-event-mouse/c13:68
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-event-kbd
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-path\x2fpci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-event-kbd/c13:67
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-id\x2fusb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-event-kbd
./.udev/links/input\x2fby-id\x2fusb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-event-kbd/c13:67
./.udev/db/usb:1-1.4
./.udev/db/usb:2-1.1
./.udev/db/usb:2-1
./.udev/db/usb:1-1
./.udev/db/usbmon:usbmon0
./.udev/db/usb:usb1
./.udev/db/usb:usb2
./.udev/db/usbmon:usbmon2
./.udev/db/usbmon:usbmon1
./input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-mouse
./input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.1-event-mouse
./input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.0-usb-0:1.1:1.0-event-kbd
./input/by-id/usb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-mouse
./input/by-id/usb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-event-mouse
./input/by-id/usb-ServerEngines_SE_USB_Device_40151554C56504-event-kbd
./usbmon2
./bus/usb
./bus/usb/002
./bus/usb/002/003
./bus/usb/002/002
./bus/usb/002/001
./bus/usb/001
./bus/usb/001/003
./bus/usb/001/002
./bus/usb/001/001
./usbmon1
./usbmon0
```

Output from /var/log/messages

```
Dec  1 15:24:31 vh01-tp kernel: usb 1-1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
Dec  1 15:24:31 vh01-tp kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0409, idProduct=0056
Dec  1 15:24:31 vh01-tp kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec  1 15:24:31 vh01-tp kernel: usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
Dec  1 15:24:31 vh01-tp kernel: usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: TSST corp
Dec  1 15:24:31 vh01-tp kernel: usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 000000000001
Dec  1 15:24:31 vh01-tp kernel: usb 1-1.4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Dec  1 15:24:39 vh01-tp init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process ended, respawning
```

Some output from /var/log/dmsg

```
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0020
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 2
usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0020
usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
usb 1-1.4: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0409, idProduct=0056
usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1.4: Product: USB Mass Storage Device
usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: TSST corp
usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 000000000001
usb 1-1.4: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
ata2.00: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata2.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata1.00: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
ata1.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953459632 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 6b 00 00 08
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
 sda: sda1 sda2
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
usb 2-1.1: new full speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0000, idProduct=0000
usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 2-1.1: Product: SE USB Device
usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: ServerEngines
usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 40151554C56504
usb 2-1.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

Output from /proc/bus/usb/devices. As I suspected, no driver seams to be installed.

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0409 ProdID=0056 Rev= 0.00
S:  Manufacturer=TSST corp
S:  Product=USB Mass Storage Device
S:  SerialNumber=000000000001
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=  2mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=05 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
```

Should I look somwhere else, or is the right info just in front of me?

Comment: Nevermind the question.

I'm a stupid idiot that shouldn't be allowed to sit infront of a computer. I have a hardening script that adds "blacklist usb-storage" to modprobe.d. Strange that it didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that my hardening script did a "blacklist usb-storage" in a conf file in /etc/modprobe.d. I had forgot about that.

Answer (score 3):

`/dev/dvd` is a symlink to the real block device file. Search the `dmesg` output for the CD-ROM device. Should be something like `sr0` or `scd0`. You can then make a symlink by yourself with: `sudo ln -s /dev/<dvd_device_name> /dev/dvd`.

Comment: Updated my question with output from dmsg. Can't find the s* device for usb 1-1.4. And in /dev I have the following s* devices sda, sda1, sda2, sg0, sg1, shm/, snapshot, stderr, stdin, stdout, systty.